# Google map being returned in div tags via backbone javascript but not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, rendering

I have started playing around with Geolocation, and I can get the co-ordinates etc. I want to show this in a map, but when I return the map to the div nothing gets displayed. Now I looked in the div, and the map is being returned but just not visibile. This is the div in question

Notice this seems to be just a link to a tiny map

```
  <a style="position: static; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; float: none;                 display:     inline; " target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.263519,-7.124185&amp;z=21&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"><div style="width: 62px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer; "><img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; width: 62px; height: 24px; " src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/google_white.png" draggable="false"></div></a>
```

This is what I'm doing,Html
      
    
    Home

#### Your location

```
<div data-role="content" id="location1">
<div  id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

My model is as follows

```
      bb.model.Map = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.26351898,-6.14462727),
    zoom: 20,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
});
```

My view is as follows

```
     bb.view.Location = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({  

   id: 'map',
   initialize: function(){
     this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.attributes);
 this.render();
   },
 render: function(){
 //    $('#map').replaceWith(this.el);
   $('#map').replaceWith(this.el);
      $('#location-page').page();

   },
```

}))

I'm also using the following script.

```
      <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have various problems here so we'll go top to bottom.

When you say this:

```
<div data-role="content" id="location1">
    <div  id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

The 100% width and height values on `#map` refer to the parent element so you're saying

> make `#map` the same size as `#location1`

By default, a `<div>`, like all block elements, will be as wide as its parent (assuming that there's no margins, padding, ... in the way) and be tall enough to contain its content. If you don't have any CSS that forces `#location1` to be a specific size then it will be as wide as the page (or whatever parent it has) and it will have a height of zero. That means that `#map` will also be zero pixels tall. So you'll need to make sure `#location1` has an assigned height.

When you say this in a view definition:

```
id: 'map',
```

you're only telling Backbone to set `id="map"` on the [`<div>` it creates for your view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>
> [...] `this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties, if specified. If not, `el` is an empty `div`.

Saying `id: 'map'` doesn't grab `#map` from the DOM to use as the view's `el`, it just leaves you with `<div id="map"></div>` as your view's `el`. You probably want to specify `el` in the view definition:

```
el: '#map'
```

You seem to be trying to correct the view's `el` confusion using [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). That should work, more or less, but you'd still be binding the map to a zero height `<div>` and then putting that zero height `<div>` into the DOM. Short is fine but you can't see something that is 0px tall.

Also, you don't need `Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({ ... }));`, you only need `Backbone.View.extend({ ... });`.

Assuming that you have something to give `#location1` a height, then a view like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#map',
    initialize: function() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
            this.el,
            this.model.toJSON()
        );
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        return this; // This is standard practice.
    }
});
```

should get things moving.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ue4zL/1/

Comment: Thanks that was an excellent answer. I had presumed that the map would expand the Div tag to the required height. Also this piece of code does not work, at least not in this context   $('#map').replaceWith(this.el); . returning this is something new for me. thanks for taking the time. Time for me to play around with this now.

Comment: Is there an easy way to be able to pick up the location off a user obviously you would not use the default settings. I tried usind the following

Comment: Fix your syntax errors first. Then maybe ask another question, someone else could probably sort you out before I could get to it, bit busy at work right now.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my code. Is it the model I should be updating to over-ride the defaults. Don't have access from within the function to the model. I seem to be a catch 22, but guess there is an obvious solution

Comment: I think your biggest problem is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, hence the callback function. So you can create the map, call `getCurrentPostion`, and then do whatever you want with the location in the callback function.

Comment: I see what your saying, so I create the map and then set the center for the location. I have updated my code as such, and I can hardcode the location, but how do I return the location back from the getcurrentposition function. Should I pass the map in ? http://jsbin.com/ufekam/5/watch

Comment: You need to get the map into the callback, you conveniently have `var self = this;` and the callback is a closure so you can use `self.map` to get at the map inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What I did was put   self.map.setCenter(geolocpoint,40); inside the setcurrentlocation, and this seems to work good.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this.el has a nonzero height. You are destroying #map and replacing it with something entirely new...

Comment: Will do, I had presumed the div would expand in height