# Default google map size by percentage in a mobile app?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, mobile-application

I was trying to put a map on a page in a phonegap mobile app. I want to have a default size of height:45% and width:100% of the #content div(HTML snippet shown below). Some guys told me to set the height of the  and  to 100%. But still, the map loads with a size of zero width and  height(thus invisible). Using pixels doesn't seem to be a good idea since the app targets different devices with varying sizes. How can I solve the issue? Thanks

```
 <div data-role="content" style="height:100%;">

    <div id="introvid" style="width:100%; height: 45%; ">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:100%; height:45%; min-height:45%;"> 
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: See this page "[Part 20 Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)" from Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial.

Comment: @geocodezip - I did that to no avail.Mine is a backbone based client application. I put the style on the index page. It didn't work.

Comment: perhaps this similar question might help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149349/google-map-being-returned-in-div-tags-via-backbone-javascript-but-not-displaying/13150016#13150016